# Liquid Slider not working properly in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adobe-brackets

I am working on a google chrome extension. I am using Liquid slider to help me with the popup, when I am in brackets and do live preview, I get exactly the result I want.

https://gyazo.com/d2b5e7215ff8dfab59d677fd94637a25

But when I go into google chrome to test my extension this happens.

https://gyazo.com/48ea596645f0b16305915fb144d2aad8

It is not in the tab format anymore.

I could not find any support on this, if anyone has any idea why this does not work. Is it just because I can't use Liquid Slider in my chrome extension? I have no idea. Please tell me if you need more information.

Edit: If it is not possible to fix the error and bring back the tabs, we can also just use arrows, and figure out how to delete the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome extensions have stricter security & sandboxing than regular web pages - for example, [Content Security Policy is enabled by default](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). That may explain the difference.

To get more specifics about what's going wrong, you can [debug your extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) by right-clicking the icon and selecting Inspect Popup. This will open the familiar Chrome Dev Tools where you can check the console for errors, etc. Does that give you more specifics to go on?

Comment: `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-PF9+H7KP4yzeBTGrVg8LyEMg69PnKu2aMdZ6p+GHEP8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
`                                                                                                                                         This is what I got. Now, I am new to chrome extensions, this being my first project. I do not know what any of that means.

Comment: I figured it out, the problem was that I had <script></script> in my popup.html   All I had to do was just move the script code to my popup.js Thanks for helping me out!